# phpDocumentor 2 installer fails to install symfony/Console with composer

Tags: symfony1, phpdoc, phar

I've downloaded (cloned) the github version of phpdocumentor 2 and followed the installation instructions found on the [phpdoc website](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/installation.html#manual-installation)

At the composer installation step 3 (`php composer.phar install`) I receive the following error messages

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                              
  Failed to clone http://github.com/symfony/Console via git, https and http protocols, aborting.  

- git://github.com/symfony/Console                                                              
  fatal: reference is not a tree: 1edd7b739561e87bde81ff1c2ce08bd89e92277e                      

- https://github.com/symfony/Console                                                            
  fatal: reference is not a tree: 1edd7b739561e87bde81ff1c2ce08bd89e92277e                      

- http://github.com/symfony/Console                                                             
  fatal: reference is not a tree: 1edd7b739561e87bde81ff1c2ce08bd89e92277e
```

It seems that the symfony git tree has changed, or..? Do you have any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an error int he update of the Console subtree split. Please use `php composer.phar update` instead of install. This should resolve the situation.